# Only the first event is displayed on the FullCalendar. I cannot figure out why I cannot display more than one event

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6, fullcalendar

I can display only the first event on the FullCalendar. The data are coming from the database in SQL Server using a Model in Entity Framework. I then returned a JSON object to the view. Can someone point me to the right direction so I can display all the events from the database?

**CalendarView**

```
      <!DOCTYPE html>

     @{
          Layout = null;

      }

    <html>
    <head>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.9.0/fullcalendar.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.9.0/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>




    <style type="text/css">

    body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        font-family: "Lucida Grande",Helvetica,Arial,Verdana,sans-serif;
        font-size: 14px;
    }

    #top {
        background: #eee;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
        padding: 0 10px;
        line-height: 40px;
        font-size: 12px;
    }

    #calendar {
        max-width: 900px;
        margin: 40px auto;
        padding: 0 10px;
    }
    </style>


    <script type="text/javascript">



    /*Get data from the database and load it on the FullCalendar*/
    $(window).load(function () {

        jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

            var events = [];
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "@Url.Action("GetEvents", "Calendar")",  //Get the data
                contentType: "application/json",
                success: function (data) {
                    $.each(data, function (i, v) {

                        events.push({
                            title: v.ProjectName,
                            start: moment(v.DateCreated),


                        });


                        GenerateCalendar(events);  
                    })


                },
                        error: function (error)
                        {
                            alert('Error');
                        }

            });


            function GenerateCalendar(events) {

                $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                    height: 666,
                    nowIndicator: true,
                    defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
                    columnHeaderFormat: 'ddd D MMM',
                    header: {
                        left: 'prev,next today',
                        center: 'title',
                        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
                    },

                    defaultView: 'month',                       
                    selectable: true,
                    editable: false,
                    events: events  //This allows the calendar to display only the first event.


                });

            }


        });

    });



 </script>

 </head>
 <body>


<div id="calendar"></div>


 </body>
 </html>
```

**CalendarController**

```
   public JsonResult GetEvents()
   {


        using (FacilityRequestEntities db = new FacilityRequestEntities())
        {
            var events = db.Dashboards.ToList();
            return new JsonResult { Data = events, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
        }

   }
```

**Database table, SQL Server**

```
   FaspNumberId Projectname CurrentStatus DateCreated       RequestorName        
   001          AAA         Approved      2018-11-30 01:40:00     John 
   002          BBB         Pending       2018-12-01 01:16:00     Eric 
   003          CCC         Approved      2018-12-01 03:46:00     Marie  
   004          DDD         Disapproved   2018-12-02 05:52:00     Anne
```

Comment: You don't seem to be initializing the calendar with your `events` data.  You  fetch it then do nothing with it.  Also, why not use fullcalendar's own ajax implementation rather than fetch events on your own?  https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-json-feed

Comment: @WillardSolutions I actually just started getting familiar with FullCalendar. I will look at that link you posted. Thanks!

Comment: btw you appear to be running a very old, unsupported version of fullCalendar. The latest is 3.9 but you are trying to run 1.5 - any reason for that?

Comment: @ADyson I just updated the Fullcalendar to the latest one. Thanks for pointing that to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure out the issue, by making few changes on my CalendarView. Please, see the solution below:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>

 @{
     Layout = null;

 }


 <html>
 <head>

 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
 <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.9.0/fullcalendar.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.9.0/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>



 <style type="text/css">

    body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        font-family: "Lucida Grande",Helvetica,Arial,Verdana,sans-serif;
        font-size: 14px;
    }

    #top {
        background: #eee;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
        padding: 0 10px;
        line-height: 40px;
        font-size: 12px;
    }

    #calendar {
        max-width: 900px;
        margin: 40px auto;
        padding: 0 10px;
    }
 </style>


 <script type="text/javascript">

    $(window).load(function () {


        $(document).ready(function() {

             // Fetch our events
            $.ajax({
                url: "@Url.Action("GetEvents", "Calendar")",  //Get the data from the controller,
                method: "GET",
                datatype: "json",

            }).done(function (data) {
                // Parse our events into an object called events that will later be used to initialize FullCalendar
                var events = [];

                $.each(data, function (i, v) {

                    events.push({
                        title: v.ProjectName,
                        start: moment(v.DateCreated),
                    });
                });

                $('#calendar').fullCalendar({

                     height: 666,
                    nowIndicator: true,
                    defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
                    columnHeaderFormat: 'ddd D MMM',
                    header: {
                        left: 'prev,next today',
                        center: 'title',
                        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
                    },

                    defaultView: 'month',
                    selectable: true,
                    editable: false,
                    events: events,  //Pass the new collection of events to the FullCalendar initialization function, targeting the #calendar div.
                });
            });


        });

    });



 </script>

 </head>
 <body>


 <div id="calendar"></div>


 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: it would a be a lot more helpful to future readers if you could explain what changes you had to make, so people don't have to spend time to carefully compare it to the original code in the question. If you can do that, you'll get my upvote